# custom css file in sharepoint online won't update

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-designer

I am working on an intranet in Sharepoint online.  I have added a custom css file and included it in the masterpage, after the default stylesheets.  In the sourcecode I can see it clearly and I can follow the path to its intended file.

Earlier I had no problems to check it out, edit in Sharepoint designer, save it, then checking it in and changes would apply to the site.

But now the changes I make don't seem to catch. I have cleared cache on several browsers but still no change.

The masterpage and the custom startpage are both published. No files are left checked out.

I may be a sharepoint noob, I have searched any number of forums but not found anything pertinent to my problem.

Can anyone give me a pointer in the right direction please? 
:)

Answer (score 2):

Do you save the CSS file in a document library that uses versioning? Perhaps you forgot to publish the latest version of your changes, so browsers only see your previous version.

Comment: The file is in a folder in the style library, so no, don't think that uses versioning?

Comment: By default Style Library is using versioning. Try to visit the folder in the browser as admin and check if the drop down contains publish.

Comment: Thanks, but no it doesn't - drop down has  show & edit properties, access rights, delete, version history, Connect to Outlook and Alert (not sure of the English here, working with version in Swedish)

Access was set to one person, (this site is still in development) not me but even if I added myself it didn't change. And I have admin rights for entire site collection so that shouldn't be the problem anyway. 

Thinking of deleting the file and start over again, with a new file name.

Answer (score 1):

I made an account specifically to respond to this post because I was having the same issue and found your update about creating a new CSS file helpful in determining the real issue. So I wanted to share my solution!

In the end I discovered it was our BLOB cache being enabled that was causing the issue.  We had enabled it to use image renditions.  As per the following technet article regarding configuring the BLOB cache, I removed CSS from the file types and our issue was resolved!
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc770229(v=office.15).aspx#BLOB](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc770229%28v=office.15%29.aspx#BLOB)

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You are logged in as the Site Collection administrator?
2. CTRL+F5 to get the latest .css from server?
3. When you View Source you are able to see the link to your .css file?
4. When you follow the link to the .css file and open the .css file, it has the recent changes you made?

I think you might have done this.. but make sure after publishing the .css file it is approved.

Press F12 to load IE Dev Toolbar to see what styles are being used in the elements in question. May be you have a small syntax error in the recent classes you added.

- Thanks, Karthik.

Comment: Hi, and thanx for your reply. 

1 - yes I am admin
2 - yes I have refreshed my browser, cleared cache etc, in  different browsers
3 - yes the link to the css works
4 - no, recent changes do not appear in the file I can browse to. 

What does approved mean in the circumstances? where do I do that? And how come, if I dont know that, changes I made in june worked just fine.

thanx for your patience :)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I made a copy of the css file, gave it a new name and referred to that instead, worked like a charm.

Thanks for your answers and comments all

Comment: I am stuck as well. I don't think renaming it every time I make a css change is a viable solution long term though. bummer.

Answer (score 0):

Under Site Collection Administration settings, go to SharePoint Designer settings and make sure all the checkboxes are marked including "Enable Customizing Master Pages and Page Layouts "

Also, make sure your tag that cites your custom CSS is just below the last meta tag in the head of your master page.

Lastly, remove quotes... there are additional quotes added with javascript so you don't need quotes AND have the full URL to the stylesheet or it will not work!